# Image scroller in web page

Tags: image, scroll

I want to develop an image scroller in a web page.

It must satisfy the following conditions

1. I must be able to scroll either using the navigation buttons or the mouse wheel
2. The images must wrap around in a cycle. How do I implement these ?

Hi 
jCarouselLite works fine on an independent web page but not in a joomla module

Can any one help me in this ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a [jQuery plugin](http://www.gmarwaha.com/jquery/jcarousellite/index.php) for that. You may have to add the keyboard controls yourself but t looks easy enough to extend.